# Switch to top of shiny dashboard panel via sidebarmenu

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

Considering the shiny dashboard example below (adapted from https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html). Is it somehow possible to scroll down in one tab item and when then switching to another tab item by clicking in the sideboard end up at the top of the new item instead of the same height as before?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      style = "position: fixed; overflow: visible;",
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotA", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderA", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotB", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderB", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotC", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderC", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotD", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderD", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotE", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderE", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotF", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderF", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
              
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider1", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider2", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider3", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider4", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot5", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider5", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot6", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider6", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider1)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider2)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider3)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider4)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider5)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot6 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider6)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  
  
  output$plotA <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderA)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotB <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderB)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotC <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderC)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotD <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderD)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotE <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderE)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotF <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderF)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `shinyjs`. A line of JS is executed everytime another item in the sidebar is clicked. See the `observeEvent` I added:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarID", 
                style = "position: fixed; overflow: visible;",
                menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
                menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = 'shinyjs.scrolltop = function() {window.scrollTo(0, 0)};', functions = c("scrolltop")),
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotA", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderA", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotB", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderB", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotC", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderC", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotD", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderD", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotE", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderE", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plotF", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("sliderF", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
              
      ),
      
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab content"),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider1", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider2", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot3", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider3", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot4", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider4", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot5", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider5", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(plotOutput("plot6", height = 250)),
                
                box(
                  title = "Controls",
                  sliderInput("slider6", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$sidebarID, {
    js$scrolltop()
  })
  
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider1)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider2)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider3)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider4)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot5 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider5)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plot6 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider6)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  
  
  output$plotA <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderA)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotB <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderB)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotC <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderC)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotD <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderD)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotE <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderE)]
    hist(data)
  })
  
  output$plotF <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$sliderF)]
    hist(data)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Running this code returns `Error: shinyjs: extendShinyjs: `functions` argument must be provided.`.

Comment: By the time the answer was given `extendShinyjs`' `function` argument was optional (worked with earlier versions). Please see my edit.